# Let $B\in M_{mn}(\mathbb{F})$ and $A\in M_{nq}(\mathbb{F})$ show that $range(BA)\leq range(A)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $B\in M_{mn}(\mathbb{F})$ and $A\in M_{nq}(\mathbb{F})$ show
that $\textrm{range}(BA)\leq \textrm{range}(A)$.

**This is my proof, but I have a doubt about equality (I think it's wrong)**
To prove that $\textrm{range}(BA) \leq \textrm{range}(A)$, we can use the property that $\textrm{range}(A^T) = \textrm{range}(A)$. First, notice that $BA \in M_{mq}(\mathbb{F})$, that is, $BA$ is a matrix of size $m \times q$.

Then, we can apply the property mentioned above to the matrix $BA$ and its transpose $(BA)^T = A^TB^T$. Have:

$$\textrm{range}(BA) = \textrm{range}((BA)^T) = \textrm{range}(A^TB^T) \leq \textrm{range}(A^T)$$

where the last inequality follows from the fact that matrix $A^TB^T$ is of size $q \times m$, so its range cannot be greater than the range of matrix $A^T$ of size $n \times q$.

Finally, by applying again the property $\textrm{range}(A^T) = \textrm{range}(A)$, we obtain:

$$\textrm{range}(BA) \leq \textrm{range}(A^T) = \textrm{range}(A)$$

Comment: I guess you mean rank.  $r(A^TB^T)\le r(A^T)$ since one is $q\times m$, one is $n\times q$, this is not well-inferred. To prove the statement, if you have learned linear mapping, please consider $x\mapsto Ax$ and $x\mapsto BAx$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are considering the linear transformation $BA:F^q \rightarrow F^m$. This is equivalent to considering the restriction of $B$ to the range of $A$, that is $\left.B\right|_{\text{Im}(A)}: \text{Im}(A) \rightarrow F^m$.

Then by rank-nullity, $\text{rank}(A)=\dim(\text{Im}(A))=\text{rank}(\left.B\right|_{\text{Im}(A)})+\text{nullity}(\left.B\right|_{\text{Im}(A)})=\text{rank}(BA)+\text{nullity}(\left.B\right|_{\text{Im}(A)})$ and we have proven the result.